# Sql server 2012 job history log

Tags: sql-server-2012

**SQL SERVER JOB HISTORY RETAIN**

I am getting job history in sqlserver 2012, only of 24 houres after 24 houres history automaticaly purged.
I have some jobs which are running on daily basis and required to retain history of these jobs but I am not getting those history from "VIEW HISTORY". 
It is showing only current days history
Please Help To Resolve.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the history settings on SQL Server Agent (Right-click the Agent in Management Studio, select Properties, select History in the left panel).  It sounds like your settings are keeping the history log rather low.  You'll need to increase the history limits here.

[image]